# How do I denote a list of a specific object as a return in a Swagger file?

Tags: swagger

I'm attempting to document a REST API using Swagger.  Per REST API norms, I have endpoints for each `Thing`, and the GET protocols for each endpoint are bog standard normal: `/thing/{id}` returns a single `Thing` with the matching ID you give, and `/thing/` returns a list of all valid `Things`.

The YAML for `/thing/{id}` is straightforward enough.

```
get:
  operationId: GET_thing-id
  tags:
    - Thing
  description: >-
    Gets a specific Thing.
  parameters:
    - name: token
      in: query
      required: false
      type: string
    - name: Accept
      in: header
      required: false
      type: string
  responses:
    '200':
      description: ''
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Thing'
```

Where the `$ref` refers to the following, further down the YAML file:

```
definitions:
  Thing:
    title: Thing
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        description: uuid.
```

But I find myself unsure how to handle the `/thing/` endpoint, which is supposed to simply return a list of the models above.  There seems to be no clear way to do this from perusing the Swagger spec, which I have done in depth at this point.  Does anyone have guidance on how to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  The problem was that there's slightly different things I need to define for an array and that was a real issue in tracking it down.  The solution is:

```
definitions:
  ThingArray:
    title: ThingArray
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Thing'
```

This can then be used in the `/thing/` path and it looks perfectly reasonable.